# Unipotent vs nilpotent subgroup of GL(n)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, general-linear-group, unipotent-matrices

I see the subgroup
$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1 & x \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\right\} \subset \mathrm{GL}(2)$$
written as $U$ and described as the unipotent subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(2)$ in some literature, and this makes sense to me. I sometimes see it written as $N$ and described as the standard nilpotent subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(2)$ in other literature though (maybe only for finite fields?). Similar for $\mathrm{GL}(n)$.

Which is more common or more correct?

Comment: Definitely unipotent is correct. The elements of this set are NOT nilpotent. If you raise this matrix to power, you never will get the zero matrix. Maybe the confusion is because the Lie algebra of this group is the set of nilpotent matrices.

Comment: For finite fields, it's nilpotent?

Comment: No.  Then $n$-th power of that matrix is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & n x \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. It doesn't matter what the characteristic of the field is. The diagonal entries will never be equal to zero.

Comment: @Nick: Multiplicatively, you get nilpotent groups. For example, the Heisenberg group, which is nilpotent, can be realized as the set of $3\times 3$ upper unitriangular matrices.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes you are right. There is a confusion here between "nilpotent matrix" and "nilpotent group".

Comment: @Nick: Yes, but if you are talking about groups, "nilpotent" should refer to group nilpotency, not the ring notion.

Comment: Yes, I was agreeing with you. The confusion is on my part. I thought the question was about nilpotency of the elements, rather than nilpotency of the group itself.

Comment: To me this kind of confusion is a very good reason to favor the word unipotent over the word nilpotent in this context ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

Let U = {U_x = (1 x; 0 1)} be a Unipotent group in GL2
Then we have the central series:
C^1(U) = U
C^2(U) = [U,U]= {(1 0 ; 0 1)}
which says that the group U is nilpotent.

On the other hand, if N = {N_x=(0 x; 0 0)}; which consists of nilpotent matrices since N^2=0. Then C^1(U_x) = U_x = I + N_x and
C^2(U_x) = I + (N_x)^2 = I. Hence,the descending central series C^2(U) = I.

This can be generalised to GL(n).